# Какой знак поставить?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Всё () я устал".
Какой знак поставить? Если запятая, то по какому правилу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от интонации, паузы можно поставить любой знак.

*Всё. Я устал. Всё! Я устал. Всё... Я устал. Всё — я устал.*

Чаще можно встретить запятую, которая отделяет два простых предложения в составе бессоюзного сложного: *Всё, я устал.*

[Большой толковый словарь (ГРАМОТА.РУ)](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C&all=x):

> Конец, кончено. *Между нами всё! Всё, хватит! Всё, пора домой. Больше не увидимся, всё. Вот и всё!*

Answer (score 3):

Обычно в таких (не восклицательных) предложениях ставится запятая. **Всё, я устал.**
Это сложное предложение, в котором два сказуемых.

В словаре Ефремовой:
[ВСЁ](https://xn--b1advjcbct.xn--p1ai/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5)
**2.** ***предикатив***, разг. Достаточно, довольно, хватит, конец, кончено.

> — Вот именно, я хотел сравнить… Шпеер — нацист, сукин сын, а Фукс — это истинный подвиг таланта.
>   **— Всё, я ухожу.**
>   Повернулась и пошла к лифту.
>   (Даниил Гранин)

*— Увидимся позже. **Всё, не могу больше говорить**, — и она моментально направилась к следующему столику* (И. Бойко).